# what is the Protobuf version for Acumos

Tags: protocol-buffers, acumos

What is the Protobuf version required for the Model user? 
AcumosError: A failure occurred while generating source code from protobuf: b'MMGfiPybWYusryVpTePnBbAVjcGAasJx/model.proto:1:10: Unrecognized syntax identifier "proto3".  This parser only recognizes "proto2".\n'

Answer (score 0):

Acumos requires Google protocol buffer compiler version 3 or later.  The latest is 3.6.1, binaries and source are available from https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/tag/v3.6.1

My machine happily runs this:

```
$ protoc --version
libprotoc 3.5.1
```

P.s. I wish the person who posted -1 on your question would leave a comment about why the downvote seemed appropriate. :/